# Edit intermediate table based off checkboxes

Tags: php, mysql

**My goal:**

> To change my MySql table that looks like this:

```
role_permission:
role_id    permissions_id
2          1
1          3
1          4
1          5
1          2
```

Based upon the HTML Code of this:

```
<div class="element">
    <label for="permissions">Permissions:</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="permissions[1]" value="false" checked="">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="permissions[1]" value="true" checked="">&nbsp;canPushAPK</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="permissions[2]" value="false">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="permissions[2]" value="true">&nbsp;canBeCool</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="permissions[3]" value="false" checked="">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="permissions[3]" value="true" checked="">&nbsp;canEditSettings</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="permissions[4]" value="false" checked="">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="permissions[4]" value="true" checked="">&nbsp;canManageRoles</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="permissions[5]" value="false" checked="">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="permissions[5]" value="true" checked="">&nbsp;canAddUser</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="permissions[6]" value="false">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="permissions[6]" value="true">&nbsp;canFoo</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="permissions[7]" value="false">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="permissions[7]" value="true">&nbsp;canTalk</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="permissions[8]" value="false">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="permissions[8]" value="true">&nbsp;canTest</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="permissions[9]" value="false">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="permissions[9]" value="true">&nbsp;canPoo</label>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="roleId" value="1">
```

[View as JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/YdyBX/2/)

Then based off what values are checked for "roleId" = 1, it inserts into the DB. for all unchecked, it deletes this row.

IE:
If all are checked, it will look like:

```
role_permission:
role_id    permissions_id
2          1
1          1
1          2
1          3
1          4
1          5
1          6
1          7
1          8
1          9
```

**What am I thinking:**
Two queries:

```
DELETE FROM role_permissions
WHERE role_id = ?
```

Then:

```
$query = $this->mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO role_permission(role_id,permission_id) VALUES (?,?)");
        $query->bind_param("ii", $roleId, $permissionId);
        $roleId = $_POST['roleId'];
foreach ($_POST['permissions'] as $permissionId=> $value){
    if ($value){
        $query->execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, never accept an answer you are not happy with! Including this one! You are not required to accept an answer.  I do the code 'cos i enjoy doing it. I may need the code myself and do not have it.  I would use it for 'real'. I rather like it, obviously. :-) Other people do 'crossword puzzles', i do this. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your approach will work. you seem to like HTML.

If you use an array of 'permission names' and whether acive or not, then the code is just foreach loops as follows:

Tested code: PHP 5.3.18, mysqli on windows xp (Oi, stop laffin')

```
<?php // Q22950444
// program smarter not harder...
// arrays are your friend...

$allPermissions =
        array('canPushAPK'  => false, "canBeCool" => false, "canEditSettings" => false,
              "canManageRoles" => false, "canAddUser" => false, "canFoo" => false,
              "canTalk" => false, "canTest" => false, "canPoo" => false);

$mysqlhost   = 'localhost';
$mysqluser   = 'test';
$mysqlpass   = 'test';
$myDBname     = 'testmysql';
$mysqli = new mysqli($mysqlhost, $mysqluser, $mysqlpass, $myDBname);


if (!empty($_POST['goForIt'])) {
    if (!empty($_POST['permissions'])) {
        foreach($_POST['permissions'] as $permissionName) {
            if (isset($allPermissions[$permissionName])) { // test is valid permission
                $allPermissions[$permissionName] = true;
            }
        }
    }

    // process db...
    $sql = "delete from `role_permissions` where `role_id` = ?";
    $deleteQuery = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    if ($deleteQuery === false) { // drat
        die('deleteQuery: '. $mysqli->error);
    }
    $deleteQuery->bind_param('s', $_POST['roleId']);

    $allOk = $deleteQuery->execute();
    if (!$allOk) { // drat
        die('deleteQuery: '. $deleteQuery->error);
    }

    $sql = "insert into role_permissions (role_id, permission_id) values (?, ?)";

    $insertQuery =  $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    if ($insertQuery === false) { // drat
        die('insertQuery: '. $mysqli->error);
    }

    foreach($allPermissions as $permissionName => $active) {

        if ($active) {
            // bind the variables to the ALREADY PREPARED query
            $insertQuery->bind_param('is', $_POST['roleId'], $permissionName);

            $allOk = $insertQuery->execute();
            if (!$allOk) { // drat
                die("insertQuery: $permissionName : {$insertQuery->error}");
            }
        }
    }
    echo "<br />role:  {$_POST['roleId']}: now has:<br />";
    foreach($allPermissions as $permissionName => $active) {
      echo $permissionName, ' : ', $active ? '<strong>Yippee!</strong>' : 'sadly, no', '<br />';
    }
}

?>
<form action="" method="post">
<div class="element"><!-- easy peasy way of sending out the current permissions -->
    <label for="permissions">Permissions:</label>
    <?php foreach(array_keys($allPermissions) as $permissionName): ?>
    <div>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]"
                value="<?= $permissionName ?>"
                <?= $allPermissions[$permissionName]  ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?>
                >&nbsp;<?= $permissionName; ?></label>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="roleId" value="1">
<input type="submit" name="goForIt" value="Go For It!">
</form>
```

Comment: The HTML is already generated by a PHP Class :D
Just needed the basic format. This is exactly how I was thinking about trying to do this. Although, your way seems really messy. I will wait for other answers and possibly accept this one.